# sharepoint online, set edit item view as default instead new item view

Tags: forms, sharepoint

I am working in a small SharePoint project to let school students pre-order the lunch online.
the main idea is the student can login to a school site, fill an order form.
I try use a list form to do it, just simply put a InfoPath form as web part on the home page.
When students open the site, he can fill the order form directly.
but the problem is the default view of this web part is always the new item form.  so when a student already make the order, then login to site again,
how can I let him see his order and edit it instead a new order form.

another way may be use the form library, but i don't know how can i transfer the filed from the form to a list.  because at last we still need a list instead a bunch of documents to get the summary of order.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a **custom list** and show that on the homepage?

A 'custom list' by default only has a title column but by adding more columns through the list settings you automatically add form fields on its new item form.

Since you are creating an order form you might want to **hide the title column**. Go to the settings of the list, then advanced settings, allow editing of content types. Then back in the list settings click the 'item' content type, then the title column then click the radio button for hidden.

Comment: thank you.  but i don't want to people see the whole list item, when they open the site.  basicly, one student should not see the  order detail from other students.  that's why i prefer using a web part form.

Comment: In the list settings, advanced, you can use the settings who read and modify an item. You can set it to read only items created by user